# DialogFlow training phrase

Tags: dialogflow-es, computer-science, chatbot

I am building chatbot for universities. In the training phrase, how can I add the generic parameter without specify it. For example, if I need to ask the specific course offered this semester "Is CSCI1000 offered this semester?". And my database had more than 100 courses. So I need to type more than 100 training phrases for each courses with that question. Can I put it in generic form like this "Is course_name offered this semester?". course_name will match with the specific course name that user type in. I know DialogFlow is deprecated template mode. Do we have any other way to make it simpler? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DialogFlow (DF) you can do more than that. Based on your provided information, let's assume you have 100 courses ID and names in your database. Here's the steps you should take to make DF recognize them:

- Create an entity for your courses name (course_name)
- Import course id (CSCI1000) as entity name (you can also import the name of the course as synonym, for situations where the user asks "is Computer Science offered this semester?"). You have to implement all this in your back-end
- At this point you have an Entity with name all your courses from your database (so whenever the used types the name of that course DF will recognize it). Note that you can use other tricks for creating entity using regular expressions.
- The final step, you have to create one intent 'Open courses' and and add Parameter, and for the entity use your created entity above (@course_name). Then type few training phrases. DF will detect courses id.
  This is what came to my mind since I have done something similar before. For your reference [Link to DOC](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-overview)